# Excel formula to take string value from cell and sort its characters in alphabetical order

Tags: excel, sorting, formula

Can you please help me to make Excel formula that takes string value from cell and sorts its characters in alphabetical order?

Ex.

original cell value: '**BACR**'
sorted characters cell: '**ABCR**'

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you have run into trouble.  What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: What's the function/code you're using to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT 2022-04-29:

With the advent of dynamic formula introduced in Office 365 Excel we can use an easy formula to do this:

```
=CONCAT(SORT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(,LEN(A1)),1),1,1,TRUE))
```

Original:

This UDF will sort numbers and Text character by character:

```
Function sortletter(rng As Range)
    If rng.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim srtArr() As String
    Dim i&, j&, k&
    ReDim srtArr(1 To Len(rng))
    srtArr(1) = Mid(rng, 1, 1)
    For i = 2 To UBound(srtArr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(srtArr)
            If srtArr(j) = "" Then
                srtArr(j) = Mid(rng, i, 1)
                Exit For
            ElseIf IIf(Asc(Mid(rng, i, 1)) > 96, Asc(Mid(rng, i, 1)) - 32, Asc(Mid(rng, i, 1))) <= IIf(Asc(srtArr(j)) > 96, Asc(srtArr(j)) - 32, Asc(srtArr(j))) Then
                For k = UBound(srtArr) To j + 1 Step -1
                    srtArr(k) = srtArr(k - 1)
                Next k
                srtArr(j) = Mid(rng, i, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    sortletter = Join(srtArr, "")
End Function
```

Put this is a module attached to the workbook, NOT in the worksheet or ThisWorkbook code.

Then it can be called like any other formula

```
=sortletter(A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! You rock! Thanks!