# How to use Excel VLOOKUP for same letters but different word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to find the values of words with the same letters but different order of letters. I tried using vlookup but it didn't work, any suggestions how to do that? For example, the letters are the same in the photo, but their order is different and I cannot find the value.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? If you are using Excel 365 then this could be significant

Comment: Use find() five times with wildcards

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative `LAMBDA()` related option using `REDUCE()`:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=XLOOKUP("",REDUCE(A$1:A$3,MID(D1,SEQUENCE(LEN(D1)),1),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,"",1))),B$1:B$3)
```

---

Or; spill the entire range at once wrapping the above in `BYROW()`:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=BYROW(D1:D3,LAMBDA(a,XLOOKUP("",REDUCE(A$1:A$3,MID(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(a)),1),LAMBDA(b,c,SUBSTITUTE(b,c,"",1))),B$1:B$3)))
```

---

The above would assume lookup values that are of the exact same length. To avoid false positives we should probably concatenate our starting value first:

```
=XLOOKUP(D1,REDUCE(A$1:A$3&D1,MID(D1,SEQUENCE(LEN(D1)),1),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,"",1))),B$1:B$3)
```

And respectively:

```
=BYROW(D1:D3,LAMBDA(a,XLOOKUP(a,REDUCE(A$1:A$3&a,MID(a,SEQUENCE(LEN(a)),1),LAMBDA(b,c,SUBSTITUTE(b,c,"",1))),B$1:B$3)))
```

Comment: One Query 6 different solutions just amazing!,, the solutions by you both sir, just sorts out my weekend plan, to learn more from it

Answer (score 3):

With Office 365 we can use XLOOKUP with some other dynamic array formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(CONCAT(SORT(MID(D1,SEQUENCE(,5),1),1,1,TRUE)),BYROW(MID($A$1:$A$3,SEQUENCE(,5),1),LAMBDA(A,CONCAT(SORT(A,1,1,TRUE)))),$B$1:$B$3,"")
```

This will order the letters in alphabetical order virtually so that they will find the matches.

[image]

---

If one does not have Office 365 this will be easier with vba.  Based on an older answer:  [Excel formula to take string value from cell and sort its characters in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086737/excel-formula-to-take-string-value-from-cell-and-sort-its-characters-in-alphabet/39087596#39087596)

We can use the following UDF's to return the needed sorted values:

```
Function sortletterarr(rng As Range)
    If rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    If rng.Rows.Count <= 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim out()
    out() = rng.Value
    Dim srtArr() As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim a As Long
    For a = LBound(out, 1) To UBound(out, 1)
        ReDim srtArr(1 To Len(out(a, 1)))
        srtArr(1) = Mid(out(a, 1), 1, 1)
        For i = 2 To UBound(srtArr)
            For j = 1 To UBound(srtArr)
                If srtArr(j) = "" Then
                    srtArr(j) = Mid(out(a, 1), i, 1)
                    Exit For
                ElseIf IIf(Asc(Mid(out(a, 1), i, 1)) > 96, Asc(Mid(out(a, 1), i, 1)) - 32, Asc(Mid(out(a, 1), i, 1))) <= IIf(Asc(srtArr(j)) > 96, Asc(srtArr(j)) - 32, Asc(srtArr(j))) Then
                    For k = UBound(srtArr) To j + 1 Step -1
                        srtArr(k) = srtArr(k - 1)
                    Next k
                    srtArr(j) = Mid(out(a, 1), i, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        out(a, 1) = Join(srtArr, "")
    Next a
    sortletterarr = out
End Function
```

And

```
Function sortletter(rng As Range)
    If rng.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
    Dim srtArr() As String
    Dim i&, j&, k&
    ReDim srtArr(1 To Len(rng))
    srtArr(1) = Mid(rng, 1, 1)
    For i = 2 To UBound(srtArr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(srtArr)
            If srtArr(j) = "" Then
                srtArr(j) = Mid(rng, i, 1)
                Exit For
            ElseIf IIf(Asc(Mid(rng, i, 1)) > 96, Asc(Mid(rng, i, 1)) - 32, Asc(Mid(rng, i, 1))) <= IIf(Asc(srtArr(j)) > 96, Asc(srtArr(j)) - 32, Asc(srtArr(j))) Then
                For k = UBound(srtArr) To j + 1 Step -1
                    srtArr(k) = srtArr(k - 1)
                Next k
                srtArr(j) = Mid(rng, i, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    sortletter = Join(srtArr, "")
End Function
```

Put both in a normal module attached to the worksheet.

then we can use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MATCH(sortletter(D1),sortletterarr($A$1:$A$3),0))
```

And it will return what we want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a primitive approach, but it does work if, as your post indicates, **all of your references are of a uniform length**, and *will work* (as an array formula) *in versions of Excel from 2007 upwards*:
[image: Screenshot showing proposed formula producing desired results]

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MATCH(SUM(CODE(MID(D1,ROW($1:$5),1))),MMULT(CODE(MID($A$1:$A$3,TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$5)),1)),ROW($1:$5)/ROW($1:$5)),0))
```

If your references are **not all of the same length** (5 in your example) then **this formula will not work** (even as updated in later versions of Excel, it could compute the same numeric value for 2 entirely different character sequences of unequal length).
(if you opt for the VBA solution in the first answer then [this](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/) article will show you where to put it)

**Edit 2-May-2022**

JvdV's feedback has indicated a potential issue with the foregoing so, below is an alternate approach, albeit using a helper column (C):
[image: Screenshot illustrated helper-column based approach]
the formula in column C1 is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($1:$5),1)),ROW($1:$5)),ROW($1:$5)*128)
```

(which should copied down for each cell of your data)

and the formula in F1 is

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$5,MATCH(SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(CODE(MID(E1,ROW($1:$5),1)),ROW($1:$5)),ROW($1:$5)*128),$C$1:$C$5,0))
```

Comment: I upvoted the answer as it is well thought of, however a string like `AC` would match `BB` so I don't think this is that water-tight. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you're not wrong - that would definitely be an issue if the OP's 'referencing scheme' included 3 consecutive letters, although the OP did only indicates 2 such (F & G).... but I take your point, so have edited my answer to include a more robust helper-column based approach.